# Django URL Reg-Ex

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls, python-module

*Hi all*,

**How does this expression *actually* work?**

---

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', 
   url(r'^get/(?P<app_id>\d+)/$', 'app.views.app'),
   ...
)
```

---

I understand what it *does*, at least to map a **url** entered by the user to the `app()` function in the app's view page. I also understand it is a regular expression that ends up taking the id of the app and mapping it to the url. But where is this function going? What is going on with the r'^...?P /$ (I get the d+ is a digit regex, of the id itself, but that's about it).

I also understand this url function draws from the `django.conf.urls` module.

Perhaps my misunderstanding is more buried in my lack of regex experience. Nonetheless, I need help! I do not like using things I do not understand, and *I am guilty*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take a look: `r'^get/(?P<app_id>\d+)/$'`

1. The `r''` means that assume as string characters every character inside the string quotes.
2. `^` character means the beginning of the regular expression. For example, `forget/123` won't match the expression because doesn't start with `get`, if the sign weren't there, it should've match it because it won't be forcing the matched string to begin with `get`, just that `get...`appears in the string.
3. The `$` character means the end of the expression. If absent, `get/123/xd` may match the expression and this is not desired.
4. `(?P<>)` is a way to give a *name/alias* to a group in the expression.

You should read [the python's regular expressions documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). It's very good to know about regular expressions because they're very useful.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you expand a bit on #2 as to what you mean by "won't match the expression?" I don't quite follow what you mean by why forget/123 wouldn't work. Also, what about the "?"

Comment: `forget/123` won't work because with the `^` sign you're telling the regex that the whatever comes to be matched, have to begin with `get`, so `forget` won't match, because have `for` before `get`. Did I explained myself, sorry if not, I'll try it again :)

Comment: I think that makes sense now thanks. I think I get what you're saying.

Comment: The `?` is not a single sign, is the whole grammar `(?P<>)` and as I explained, it declares an alias to the group matched inside parens.

Comment: One other question, it may seem like a really poor question, but.. what is being matched? Is it the actual url they are passing in?

Comment: Yes, the `url-path`. In other words, the part of the url after the domain. `http://www.example.com/this/is/whats/matched`

Answer (score 1):

`r` just changes how the following string literal is interpreted. Backslashes (`\`) are not treated as escape sequences, that means that the regex in the string will be used as is.

`^` at the beginning and `$` at the end match  and the end of the string respectively.

`(?P<name>...)` is a saving named group - it helps you to cut a part of url and pass it as a parameter into the view. See more in django [named groups docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#named-groups).

Hope that helps.